# Turn a number into a string php

Tags: php, html, sql, time, numbers

```
<html>...
<input type="number" nome="h" min="0" max="23">:
<input type="number" nome="m" min="0" max="59">
...</html>
```

```
<?php...
$o = strval($_GET['h']).":".strval($_GET['m']).":00";
echo $o; // "::00"
...?>
```

This is the code, I need to confront this with an sql time type whose format is 00:00:00. But I don't know how to pick up the inserted values... Can someone please help me? Of course the two input are in a form with gest as method.

P.S.: I'm still studying so probably there are so many errors... I'm sorry for my poor English as well.

Comment: `nome` is not the same as `name` in your form.

Comment: 1) There is no need to turn a number into a string in PHP (it will be done automatically where necessary). 2) Form parameters are already strings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

These inputs should be inside a form. Anyways, I'd recommend to you that you use a library like [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)(You could set the date format you want) for a better user experience instead of using text input's for dates.

Comment: OP states that they are in a form with the `get` method.